# A tool to find projects erroneously referenced by dll in Visual Studio 2008 solutions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution containing a lot of projects with references to each other.

I didn't create the solution, and a lot of references that could be made by project are actually made by dll (referencing the dll of the /bin/Debug folder of the project). This is of course a problem since it creates weird behaviour when you clean or rebuild the solution, like the compiler complaining about dll versions not being OK.

I don't seem to be able to spot easily which projects are erroneously referenced by dll, so my only option now seems to look into the references from each .csproj files to spot the errors and correct them.

The problem is that my source control holds around 100 solutions with the same potential issues, each one containing tens of projects. Doing it manually may take a lot of time, so I was wondering if there is any tool out there that can rebuild references and dependencies easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used a generic solution, involving a grep tool to find all .csproj files containing /bin/Debug.

Answer (score 0):

A tool such as [ReSharper by Jet Brains](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) may be what you're looking for.

This will allow you to see which references in your projects are not being used. (and more)

Comment: I know how to user Resharper to add/remove necessary/unnecessary "using" directives, but I don't know how to manage the project references with it.